# How to run long live background service on Android?

Tags: android, service

I have an application which is for searching colleges, and is running a background service to listen the server for updates, new messages, califications, etc. But in the newest versions of Android (10 and above) the service finish when the user close the app (in the foreground and background).

The question is: what Kind of service or worker (or something) can I implement to listen the server for real time notifications despite the app being closed?

What I tried: service, intent service, workmanager. This solutions finishes when the app is kill. And also foreground service (actually i'm doing this) that works well but has to show fixed icon to notify the user the service is working, and when the app have to show a new notificacion for other reason it won't change (it's like the foreground would have a exclusive priority).

What I don't want: do 'tricks' like send broadcast to another class and restart the service or trigger alarm manager. This things not work and if maybe works cant get so far.

Comment: probably a Foreground Service. but that will have non cancelable notification in tray . u might wanna switch approach . If u just want to listen to notification why not just use FCM ?

Comment: https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/android.os.StrictMode/setThreadPolicy . you can use strict mood.  you can find more about strict mode from here-> https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/walk-through-hell-with-android-strictmode-7e8605168032

Comment: ADM, actually i'm implementing foreground service and works well but i think is not good experience for user, i edited the question and described the points.